# How send POST request of form Fetch Vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form with a field for entering text and when clicking on the button I have to send a request with the value from the input

How can i do this?

[image]

```html
<div class=" select__body" v-if="addedForm === 3">
  <div class="select-item" v-on:click="PostReqests()">Value 1</div>
  <div class="select-item" v-on:click="closeForm()">Value 2</div>
  <div class="select-item" v-on:click="closeForm()">Value 3</div>
  <div class="select-item" v-on:click="closeForm()">Value 4</div>
  <div class="select-item" v-on:click="closeForm()">Value 5</div>
  <div class="select-item-nh">
    <div class="added-form">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control select-item-add">
      <button class="form-control" v-on:click="closeForm()">Add to</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'Index',
  data() {
    return {
      post: [],
      data: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async PostReqests() {
      const request = await fetch("https://localhost:8000/addobject", {
        method: "POST",
      })
      console.log(request)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to send `data` to the server?

Comment: i want send input value

Comment: where is it stored?

Comment: I want to send a post request to the same page so that there are no errors in the network and console, but there is a value from the input

Comment: You should bind the selected value to a data property then post it using that method

Comment: Ok. How do you do it? :D

Comment: please share the template containing the select input that you're using

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim i edit post, check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not used stored the value of input, you have to use v-model for that. For more info read [Form Input Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html).
You can try the below code

```html
<select v-model="selected">
  <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
  <option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
  <option>Value 3</option>
</select>
<input v-model="name" placeholder="edit me">
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'Index',
  data() {
    return {
      post: [],
      data: [],
      name:'',
      selected:''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async PostReqests() {
      const request = await fetch("https://localhost:8000/addobject", {
        method: "POST",
        name: this.name, // sending the name input
        selected: this.selected // sending the option which was selected from dropdown
      })
      console.log(request)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not for my case, of course, but thanks, I was able to adjust for myself :)